# How do I create a bulleted list in Cete Dynamicpdf?

Tags: c#

Have had a look at the Cete DynamicPDF documentation but can't seem to find anything about creating a bulleted list.
Surely this must be possible?

Comment: Have tried using UL and LI in the HTML by the way and doesn't seem to work. Provides a list but not the bullets.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like this is what you're after

http://www.dynamicpdf.com/support/net_help_library_09_07/ceTe.DynamicPDF~ceTe.DynamicPDF.PageElements.UnorderedList.html

In C#, this would be something like the following (untested)

```
var list = new UnorderedList(0, 0, width, height, font, fontSize, UnorderedListStyle.Disc);
list.Items.Add("Item 1");
list.Items.Add("Item 2");
list.Items.Add("Item 3");

currentPage.Elements.Add(list);
```